# Copying lines from one file to another using sed and shell variables

Tags: shell, sed, variable-substitution

I've been trying to figure out how to copy lines from one file to the end of another using sed with some shell variables.

```
sed -n "$var1,$var2'p'" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

I've tried that and many close variations but no cigar. Could someone please enlighten me about the correct syntax? Thanks.

#### EDIT

So I tried to suggestions below but now I get this error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: invalid usage of line address 0
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `*'"
```

#### EDIT

Ok these suggestions helped and I found another issue and now my script is running flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: What error do you receive when running the sed command in your question? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/537555/edit) your post and provide that information.

Comment: `> file2.txt` will *overwrite* `file2`: if you want to append the copied lines to the end of the file, use `>> file2.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freddy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537558/18887) works, but [lacks an explanation](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5395). The `sed` format that you are probably aiming for is something like

```
sed -n 4,6p file1.txt
```

Where I've used `4` and `6` as dummy numbers.

Let's examine your expression, using these dummy numbers again, and the `echo` command.

```
$ var1=4
$ var2=6
$ echo "$var1,$var2'p'"
4,6'p'
```

Because you enclosed the `'`s in the `"`s, they are interpreted literally, and you are literal `'`s to the sed command. Hence, when you try to run your command:

```
$ sed -n "$var1,$var2'p'" file1.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `''
```

### Solution

You can remove the `'`s from your expression, but this would change the variable name to `$var2p` instead. Hence, as Freddy suggests, you can use `{…}` to explicitly enclose the variable name(s). i.e.

```
sed -n "${var1},${var2}p" file1.txt
```

You can test if this works by putting an echo before the command. An alternative format is

```
sed -n "$var1,$var2"p file1.txt
```

but IMO it's less readable.

Finally, as steeldriver [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537555/copying-lines-from-one-file-to-another-using-sed-and-shell-variables#comment996744_537555), if you are aiming to append to the file, use `>> file2.txt` instead of `> file2.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Use curly braces around your variable names:

```
sed -n "${var1},${var2}p" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

The braces around the first variable are not needed, but better make it consistent.